# How would I display a single form label with the required class above two text fields using Laravel and Bootstrap 4

Tags: laravel, bootstrap-4, field, required

I'm using Laravel and Bootstrap 4.2.1 and would like to display a form label over two **required** in-line text fields. I can get the label over the two fields by placing the form label outside of a form group but I am unable to get the red asterisk (*) display next to the form label. I've placed my code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/q31hmrLt/) in jsfiddle.

```
    <label for="contact_first_name" class="form-label required">Contact Name</label>
    <div class="form-group mb-3">
        <div class="row">
           <div class="col-md-6">
              <input class="form-control" id="contact_first_name" name="contact_first_name" type="text"
                     placeholder="First Name" value="" required>
           </div>
           <div class="col-md-6">
              <input class="form-control" id="contact_last_name" name="contact_last_name" type="text" 
                     placeholder="Last Name" value="" required>
           </div>
       </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a span tag with `class="text-danger"` or `style="color:red"` inside the label tag and the * in it. Either way, you will get an * sign with the label.

Below, I have used the bootstrap approach of adding `class="text-danger"` to the span tag.

```
<label for="contact_first_name" class="form-label required">Contact Name 
  <span class="text-danger">*</span>
</label>
<div class="form-group mb-3">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <input class="form-control" id="contact_first_name" name="contact_first_name" type="text"
             placeholder="First Name" value="" required>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <input class="form-control" id="contact_last_name" name="contact_last_name" type="text" 
             placeholder="Last Name" value="" required>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Here is the link to the Jsfiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/3w45qxfe/)

Answer (score -1):

@AhmadKarimi Thank you for your comment and solution. I just figured it out (by accident) while working on a different form. I needed to drop the label form control down one level inside of the form-group. It doesn't appear to work in jfiddle though.

```
    <div class="form-group mb-3">
       <label for="contact_first_name" class="form-label required">Contact Name</label>
        <div class="row">
           <div class="col-md-6">
              <input class="form-control" id="contact_first_name" 
                     name="contact_first_name" type="text"
                     placeholder="First Name" value="" required>
           </div>
           <div class="col-md-6">
              <input class="form-control" id="contact_last_name" 
                     name="contact_last_name" type="text" 
                     placeholder="Last Name" value="" required>
           </div>
       </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You are welcome. You mean the link I have provided for the JSfiddle doesn't work or the code in the JSfiddle doesn't work as you expected?

Comment: Your Jsfiddle link works.  The modification I made to my existing code didn't appear to work in Jsfiddle.